# What should I use for "Distinguished Name" in our Keystore for the Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, keytool

I'm about to release an application in the Android Market. I need to generate a keystore to sign my application. The docs are a little spares on what I'm support to put into for the `-dname` param.

Here is the line I'm using:

```
keytool -genkey -v -alias release -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=mydomain.com" -keystore my.keystore -validity 10000
```

What is required in the `-dname` (Distinguished Name) field? I found out that I can include the `CN` field. Are there other fields that I must put in before the Market will accept the app? Any good optional ones to put in?

**Updated**
I found out I can examine other apk's by using:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs nameof.apk
```

Here are some examples:

- from http://slideme.org/  `X.509, CN=SlideME, OU=SlideME, O=SlideME, L=Seattle, ST=WA, C=US`
- Opera Mini   `X.509, CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Opera Software ASA, L=Oslo, ST=Unknown, C=NO`
- Another random app,  `X.509, CN=Romeo Ordos, O=GHOR Corp., L=Donetsk, C=UA`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use the distinguished name that corresponds to your company. Here is a list of the types of components that you can use:

[image: dn table]

As far as I know, you can use a complete *Distinguised Name* separating each component by a comma. For instance, in your case you could use: `CN=christophercotton.com,L=Franklin`.

Comment: Which ones are required for the Android Market place? What are the common ones developers are using when releasing applications?

Comment: Usually, they only use the company name and/or URL.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to match what I was just able to determine by examining other apks.

Comment: Where does this table come from?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, those information are not used/display by Google Play.

Comment: because people are lame. Thanks for the answer